# pyOptSparse Error: There was an error importing the compiled snopt module

Tags: openmdao

I am using SNOPT V7.2.4, openMDAO V1.7.2, pyOptSparse, Linux Mint V17.0

I copied all the .f files under /src folder of SNOPT into /pyoptsparse/pySNOPT/source/
then I run "python setup.py build"
last I run "sudo python setup.py install"

No error was given during the above procedures.
However, when I tried to do optimization using SNOPT, I got the following error:
pyOptSparse Error: There was an error importing the compiled snopt module

and if I go to the folder of snopt.so, run "python", and run "from . import snopt", I got the following error:
ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package

Did I do anything wrong when I install SNOPT under pyOptSparse?
Any help is very appreciated.

Henry

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

The procedures above are correct and will install pyOptSparse with SNOPT under /usr/local/.

However, do not know when and how I installed a copy of pyOptSparse under ~/.local/, which is a hidden folder, while the openMDAO is installed under /usr/local/.

After deleted the copy under ~/.local/, it works.

Henry